# Loading file from the same directory doesn't work unless I specify the full path

Tags: php, wordpress

So I have this line of code inside a WordPress plugin. The code file is in the same folder as the XML file I'm trying to load. When I remove the full path and leave just the filename I get an I/O error.

```
$dom->load("/home/tapadmin/public_html/demo10/wp-content/plugins/".
    "agentmanager/fielddefs.xml");
```

What's the correct way to load the XML file so I don't have to specify the full path?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The relative paths you specify should be relative to the directory of the originally called PHP file, not the one in which you're doing the include.

So, if a page requests `/a/index.php` and that includes `/a/b/inc.php.inc`, a relative path in `inc.php.inc` will be relative to `/a/`, not `/a/b/`<sup>†</sup>.

Consider using `dirname(__FILE__)` instead to get the directory of the current file.

<sup>†</sup> If the extension properly respects the virtual directory.